# Searching a document and separating out regexes in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have this old document I'm helping to clean up and transform into datasets. It's a study that was done in the form of interviews, but unfortunately the people who conducted it included shorthand notes that are mixed in with interviewees' responses. The first step of this process is for me to separate those notes from the responses. Then I want to create a .csv that has one column with the responses and another column with the notes.

Here's an example of what the data in the study currently looks like (from a little test.txt file I made):

```
$ AKAR3NDA.S+ QRUSS/)+ A BLAJ3R
0
FIN ABIXU/BRIVNS+TELE
IB3G81S+R1.B+ QI KOPIRN /AKCENT CLN VERBS+TAM XX(010
```

What I'm having trouble with is using Python's re module to actually pick out any of the regular expressions I'm searching for. For now I'm testing this by just seeing if I can print the separate notes and responses, so I'll leave the .csv part out of my code. Here's my code as I have it:

```
1 import re
2 
3 notation = r"(^\+ | \+$ | ^- | -$ | \+ BUT\b | - BUT\b | ^\$ | \$$ | ^\+\$ | \+\$$ | ^-\$ | -\$ | DRWG | QB\b | QT\b | QBF | QTF | QFR | ^= | =$ | Q a Q | QP\b | QM/Y | QF/Y | ^\* | \*$ | QU\b | Q-U | QUU | QR\b | QRR | QH\b | QS\b | QW\b | Q-W | QAP | Q-AP | QN\b | QNN | QOF | QOOF | QK\b | Q-K | QLIT | QV\b | QEM | QVL | QDG | QAMER | QHUM | QELSW | QRTR | QSMT | QOTW | QNEX | QET\b | QPOL | QRUSS | QRUM | QHUNG | QGERM | QSYN | QGL\b | QGLY | QYID | QGLE | QENG | QI GL | QANG | QI\b | ^\) | \)$ | ^\)\+ | \)\+$ | ^\)- | \)-$ | ^\)= | \)=$ | EQ | \|\| | QCF | QZZ | QZT | \.\.\.{1} | QETC | QVB | QADJ | QINF | QNOUN | /[^/]+/ | \b/ | \bCM\b | \bCLN\b | \bSC\b | \bXX\b | QQ\b | ^0\b | ^O\b | QNT | Q-T | QLAT | QTA | QNP | QMEMX | \u2721 | QED\b | QEDS | \(/[0-9]* | \([0-9]* | \(\$[0-9]* | \(\( | QEDN | OVRPMP | MISPMP | MISTD)"
4 
5 notesSeparate = []
6 
7 with open("test.txt") as f:
8   data = f.readlines()
9 
10 for line in data:
11   newRow = []
12   notes = str(re.findall(notation, line))
13   response = str(re.sub(notation, "", line))
14   newRow.append(response)
15   newRow.append(notes)
16   notesSeparate.append(newRow)
17 
18 print notesSeparate
```

I also realize that regex is ugly and long, but I'm not sure how to format it so please any pointers on that are welcome too. Anyway, what I get when I run that file is the following output.

```
[['$ AKAR3NDA.S+ QRUSS/)+ A BLAJ3R\n', '[]'], ['0\n', '[]'], ['FIN
ABIXU/BRIVNS+TELE\n', '[]'], ['IB3G81S+R1.B+KOPIRN /AKCENTVERBS+TAM
XX(010', "[' QI ', ' CLN ']"]]
```

What I want to be getting is:

```
[['AKAR3NDA.S+ A BLAJ3R\n', ('$', 'QRUSS/)+')], ['0\n', ('')], ['FIN
ABIXU/BRIVNS+TELE\n', ('')], ['IB3G81S+R1.B+KOPIRN /AKCENTVERBS+TAM',
(' QI ', ' CLN ', 'XX(010')]]
```

I know this is all so messy, but that's kind of the point - I'm trying to take something that's super messy and make it less so. I can't tell you how much I'll appreciate some direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is something you're looking for, but this should make it  at least
*run* quicker - if you care about that.
It probably won't make it any easier to manage.

Btw, I assume that your regex is *expanded* (i.e. ignore whitespace ).
Also, why this particular codepoint `\u2721  ✡    STAR OF DAVID` ?

`(?:(?:^(?:\$|\)[+=-]?|\*|\+\$?|-\$?|[O0]\b|=))|(?:(?:\$|\)[+=-]?|\*|\+\$?|-|=)$)|Q[BHKNPRSTUVW]\b|(?:(?:[+-]BUT|Q(?:E[DT]|GL|[IQ]))\b)|(?:\b(?:/|(?:C(?:LN|M)|SC|XX)\b))|\|{2}|\.{3}|/[^/]+/|\(/\d*|\(\d*|\(\$\d*|\(\(|-\$|\u2721|(?:DRWG|EQ|MIS(?:PMP|TD)|OVRPMP|Q(?:-(?:AP|[KTUW])|A(?:DJ|MER|NG|P)|BF|CF|DG|E(?:D[NS]|LSW|M|NG|TC)|F(?:/Y|R)|G(?:ERM|L[EY])|HU(?:M|NG)|I(?:GL|NF)|L(?:AT|IT)|M(?:/Y|EMX)|N(?:EX|OUN|[NPT])|O(?:F|OF|TW)|POL|R(?:R|TR|U(?:M|SS))|S(?:MT|YN)|T[AF]|UU|V[BL]|YID|Z[TZ]|aQ)))`

Formatted

```
 (?:
      (?:
           ^ 
           (?:
                \$
             |  \) [+=-]? 
             |  \*
             |  \+\$? 
             |  -\$? 
             |  [O0] \b
             |  = 
           )
      )
   |  (?:
           (?: \$ | \) [+=-]? | \* | \+\$? | - | = )
           $ 
      )
   |  Q [BHKNPRSTUVW] \b 
   |  (?:
           (?:
                [+-] BUT
             |  Q
                (?: E [DT] | GL | [IQ] )
           )
           \b 
      )
   |  (?:
           \b 
           (?:
                /
             |  (?:
                     C
                     (?: LN | M )
                  |  SC
                  |  XX
                )
                \b 
           )
      )
   |  \|{2}
   |  \.{3}
   |  / [^/]+ /
   |  \(/ \d* 
   |  \( \d* 
   |  \(\$ \d* 
   |  \(\(
   |  -\$
   |  \u2721 
   |  (?:
           DRWG
        |  EQ
        |  MIS
           (?: PMP | TD )
        |  OVRPMP
        |  Q
           (?:
                -
                (?: AP | [KTUW] )
             |  A
                (?: DJ | MER | NG | P )
             |  BF
             |  CF
             |  DG
             |  E
                (?: D [NS] | LSW | M | NG | TC )
             |  F
                (?: /Y | R )
             |  G
                (?: ERM | L [EY] )
             |  HU
                (?: M | NG )
             |  I
                (?: GL | NF )
             |  L
                (?: AT | IT )
             |  M
                (?: /Y | EMX )
             |  N
                (?: EX | OUN | [NPT] )
             |  O
                (?: F | OF | TW )
             |  POL
             |  R
                (?:
                     R
                  |  TR
                  |  U
                     (?: M | SS )
                )
             |  S
                (?: MT | YN )
             |  T [AF] 
             |  UU
             |  V [BL] 
             |  YID
             |  Z [TZ] 
             |  aQ
           )
      )
 )
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that - I'm going to give that a try and see if it improves my code. To answer your question about the Star of David unicode, the document I'm trying to clean is OCRed (which I'm sure will introduce a whole new set of challenges once I put this code into practice). One of the characters in it might come out looking like a Star of David so I included it to be safe.

And I'm actually not sure what expanding/ignoring whitespace is... Can you explain or point me to a good resource?

Comment: @bkula - Here is what's happening. `sub(notation, "", line)` doesn't match anything, _newRow_ is appended with _[original line]_.  `re.findall(notation, line)` doesn't find anything, _newRow_ is appended with _[]_. The basic problem is that in an effort to format the regex, nothing is matching because you have placed literal _spaces_ around the things you'd like to match, but the spaces aren't actually in the source. Try the ignore whitespace flag when calling `sub()` or `findall()` or add the inline modifier `(?x)(?: <your regex> )` _at the beginning of the string_.

Comment: A tip. You may want to get this app [RegexFormat](http://www.regexformat.com) and let it format and compress it for you.

Comment: Thanks so much! I wound up making a couple additional changes to the regex you posted, but it's working like a dream now. 

It looks like RegexFormat is only for Windows - do you know of an OS X version?

Comment: I think it's bound to Windows for now, but I can recommend to the developer. How many users on OS X ?

Comment: You know though, you might be able to install Windows on OS X via software like _VirtualBox_. The regexformat is pretty compatible for standard Windows.